# Analyzing two different regression lines with independent and control variables

Tags: regression, stata, model

I'm working on a research paper evaluating the data on a regime’s violation of its citizens’ physical integrity rights and civil conflict. Below are excerpts from my paper regarding the following regression models. I'm not sure if I analyzed the data correctly, so I would appreciate a second opinion. The original four independent variables (PolPris, Torture, etc.) are categorical; a country is either a 0, 1 or 2 depending on how frequently it engages in each behavior. The dependent variable (civil conflict) is also categorical: yes/no. Democracy and Autocracy are both measured on a scale of 1-10 based on how democratic or autocratic the country is. In addition to double checking my analysis, I would also appreciate opinions as to whether or not each regression model allows me to accept or reject the research hypothesis: a regime’s violation of its citizens’ physical integrity rights affects civil conflict.

"For the 154 observations in this regression model, the amount of variance in civil conflict that is due to a regime’s violation of its citizens’ physical integrity rights is 0.3768, or 37.6 percent, which means that only 37.6 percent of the dependent variable is explained by the independent variables. The root mean squared error – which measures how well the model predicts a correct dependent variable – is .27542; in other words, when predicting civil conflict, the model is incorrect by an average of 27.5 percent.

For the 149 observations for this regression model, the R-Squared is 0.3965, which is very similar to the R-Squared statistic from the first regression model (.3768.). This means that 39.6 percent of civil conflict can be explained by the independent and control variables. The root mean squared error is .2799, which again, is remarkably similar to the root mean square error of the initial regression model (.27542.) This means that, on average, the model is off by 27.9 percent when predicting civil conflict."

[image]

Comment: You should cross-reference your earlier question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182926/can-someone-please-explain-what-this-regression-model-means  Several comments there have not received a reply from you, and I think members here might be disappointed by that. But this now exposes that you are fitting a linear probability model to a binary response Many researchers would want to recommend instead a logit or similar model. The regression model is also implicitly very optimistic that you have **interval scale measurement on all your predictors**.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox. I'm still trying to figure out how this website works.

Comment: There is no mystery: it's like any discussion in any medium in most respects. People answered your question and made other comments. There is no rule that you must reply to anything, but equally asking a related question does usually and minimally imply a cross-reference.